# merge two csv files/Extract data using two csv file in shell(using awk)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two CSV files

csv 1:

```
a0,|a1|a2|a3|
b0,|b1|b2|b3|
c0,|c1|c2|c3|
```

csv 2:

```
a2,5
a3,7
c3,10
d6,3
b2,6
```

output(can be unsorted):

```
a0,a2(5);a3(7)
b0,b2(6)      
c0,c3(10)     
others,d6(3)
```

I tried using grep and do it. But I think it will be lengthy and time taking.

```
#My tried code
while IFS= read -r line
do
  f=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f1)
  f1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f2)
  echo "$(cat csv1.csv | grep "|$f|" | cut -d, -f1),$f($f1)" >> output
done < csv2.csv
```

Output something I am able to produce

a0,a2(5)
a0,a3(6)
c0,c3(6)

Can anyone help me to achieve the output expected in shell script??

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add your efforts in your post and let us know then? Also is your file `|` delimited?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry about deliminators. I have updated the post with my efforts. My code will take much time if we have a large amount of data.

I can have any deliminators. As I am producing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed delimiters so adding this solution now(written and tested with shown samples).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$3)
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  num=split($2,array,"|")
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(array[i] in a){
      val=(val?val ";":"")array[i] "(" a[array[i]] ")"
    }
  }
  $2=val
  val=""
}
1
' FS="," OFS="," file2 file1
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$3)
  a[$2]=$3
  next
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($3,array,",")
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(array[i] in a){
      val=(val?val ",":"")array[i] "(" a[array[i]] ")"
    }
  }
  $3=val
  val=""
}
1
' FS="|" OFS="|"  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Comment: @B100d, Since you changed your files so I added EDIT solution too now.

Comment: It would not work, if an input field contained an embedded comma, for example `"a,2",5`, or embedded newlines.

Comment: @user1934428, I will add fair warning in my solution now, also I will try to edit this corner case, though OP didn't mention about it

Comment: The OP didn't have it in the example, but he said that the input was CSV. From this, I conclude that it may be any valid CSV, including multiline fields. These sometimes spring into existence, when the CSV has been exported from a spreadsheet program.

Comment: @B100d, could you please do let us know if your actual Input_file can have commas or any other input apart from shown samples please? We could write more reboust answer then

Comment: @user1934428, sure, I messaged op on same now for more clarification.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 actual data is same as Csv1 and CSV 2

Comment: @user1934428 I made some changes and it is working as expected.